# ¿Cómo habilitar acceso a web alojada en IIS bloqueado por firewall?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012

Tengo una página web ya alojada en el IIS, lo que sucede es que restauré las opciones de firewall, antes podía acceder desde otra computadora que estuviera en red, o incluso externamente con la IP publica, hasta ahí normal, ahora sucede que no lo puedo ahcer, la página no me responde, pero en el localhost si abre normalmente.

La cuestión es que si desactivo el Firewall puedo acceder normalmente, pero pues no puedo dejar el firewall abajo por seguridad.

Ya tengo activadas las opciones de *Servicios World Wide Web* y los de los *Servicios seguros de WWW* pero aún no funciona.

Comment: Poniendo una excepción en el firewall para el puerto 80?

Comment: Agregué la excepción por puerto directamente al puerto 80 pero sigue sin funcionar, al habilitar el firewall pierdo el acceso a la web

Comment: Siguiendo [estos pasos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16998955) tampoco?

Comment: Los acabo de verificar y no, siguen sin funcionar, activo todas las reglas de esos y no, sigue bloqueado el acceso, mira https://imgur.com/a/Kh1ib

Comment: Depende que datos se necesiten, osea, creo que les dije todo :/ no sé qué mas habilitar o vainas así

Comment: que tipo de web es? no necesitará algún otro puerto abierto ademas del 80?

Comment: Es una pagina web de aspx, por eso el IIS, se le asignó el puerto 8020, pero el lio es que ninguna de las paginas que hay, (hay desde el puerto 8017 hasta el 8060 mas o menos) se abren al activar el firewall, y ni aún agregando una nueva página la abre, es como si todo lo del IIS estuviera bloqueado

Comment: No entiendo bien como es eso de que varias paginas tienen diferentes puertos...estas usando iis o el el server de depuración de visual studio? Intenta de todas maneras abrir esos puertos manualmente en el firewall

Comment: Es el IIS normal, creo un sitio, le asigno un puerto disponible y accedo y ya, nada del otro mundo

Comment: En ese caso, tienes que abrir en el firewall manualmente los puertos que hayas seleccionado, si no estas usando los puertos 80 y 443 que son los estandar para http y https

Comment: Es decir, crear una excepción de firewall por cada uno de los puertos que vaya habilitando para cada nuevo sitio web que tenga en IIS si?

Comment: Eso es. Pero de momento prueba con uno y mira a ver si funciona

Comment: Parece que eso es lo que funciona, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que hice fue crear una excepción en el firewall que permitiera las conexiones a los rangos de puertos que yo necesitaba, en este caso, hice una excepción que permitiera la conexión usando los puertos 8016-8070 y listo, tenia el firewall arriba y permite el acceso a los sitios web